# Get Start Button Back in Win Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows server, and it's missing the Start Menu button.  It's got the charms, but I'd rather not wait for them to appear after moving my mouse.

I've tried the guides online, but they seem to be outdated as all they do is add folders to the Taskbar.

Current:
[image]

Desired:
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be spending much time looking at it anyway. PowerShell is your friend.

Comment: Its too bad you can't downvote comments like the one above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no Windows Start button in Windows Server 2012. You can "get" one by using a third party utility, like Classic Shell.

Comment: For future users, Classic Shell is no longer being developed. New developers took it on and new development of Open Shell is here: https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu

Answer (score 7):

Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8 never had a start button, R2 and 8.1 brought it back. Your only options are using the charms menu or using the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Drag your mouse to the very right edge of the screen, you'll get the slider window. There's a start button on it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the pointer in the *very* bottom left corner, if you hover over the few pixels in that area the Start button appears:

[image]

(Tested on Windows Server 2012 (not R2) as a guest in VirtualBox.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have Windows Server 2012 that doesn't have an Start Button.
The next release, Windows Server 2012 R2 does come with an Start Button